# How to make hot chocolate drink thicker?

Tags: chocolate

How do you make a cup of hot chocolate drink so that it's sweet and thick and maintains the chocolate taste?

I haven't been able to make anything acceptable by melting chocolate, adding sugar, milk or water. At best it tasted like crude cocoa drink. My cooking skills are very low, so please describe every step thoroughly.

Comment: I have no idea why 3 other people would have closed this as off-topic. I personally find it a very good question and would have upvoted if it wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: @rumtscho they must have seen it as recipe request.  made some edits to OP's question to make more clear.

Comment: Basically I was asking for a recipe, since a list of ingredients clearly isn't enough for me to produce a good drink from. But thanks for nothing.

Comment: Cornflour can be added to make it thicker                                         -Follow on bharatkumarr.blogspot.in

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is Italian Hot Chocolate which is thick and smooth.

You can thicken normal hot chocolate with arrowroot or cornstarch and you're there.  If you search for Italian hot chocolate you can find recipes such as [this one](http://www.bellalimento.com/2012/01/11/how-to-make-italian-hot-chocolate/) which is made with:

- real chocolate (bitter sweet)
- Whole Milk (sometimes cream)
- Cornstarch
- Sugar

If you can't find good bittersweet chocolate (don't use the bakers stuff), you can buy any good dark chocolate and forgo most of the sugar to keep the balance.  Keep the heat super low and take your time melting the chocolate.

It is super easy to make, and if you start with quality chocolate (Lindt and better) it will be a crowd pleaser and then some.